# Profiles and Record Types

Tags: profile, record-type

We have a custom object with 6 record types.

I would like to know whether it is possible to determine  what all profiles have access to a specific record type from this custom object .

Any pointers on this would be of much help..tx

Comment: This is not my answer but https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm#profilerecordtypevisibility_title

I think if you use metadata API and  use ProfileRecordTypeVisibility in that you should be able to get. Haven't tried it myself , will do so and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Profile Comparator for Chrome (plugin) makes this possible for two profiles at a time. You have to uncheck the enhanced user profile view in de UI settings.